# Node.js and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, server, shippo

I am new to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) and I'm trying to run a script that uses **Node.js**' `require()` when a **html** button is clicked but it simply says `"require" is not recognized` (which makes sense).

So how exactly can I activate my node.js script when the HTML button is clicked in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Node runs on the server not the browser.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I get that, which is why I said it made sense not to run and asked what I can do...

Answer (score 1):

You could use some library like [express](http://expressjs.com/) to handle `requests` and `responses` easely. In your case when the button is clicked a `request` is done to a server thats running node, the server handles the request and then sends back a `response`.

See more in [Anatomy of an HTTP Transaction](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/) in Node's oficial docs.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Node.js is to write server-side code in Javascript. This means that you can't use this functionality in the browser.

However, to accomplish what you were asking, you can use a framework like [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) (a node package with Node.js)

Then, you need to set up an ajax request from the front-end that communicates with your server. You can launch an asynchronous call once your button is clicked, which can be received on the back-end using Express.js

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a module wrapper to have `require` feature in browser.

There are several tools can accomplish this task, AFAIK, the most popular of them are [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) and [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Webpack is complex but very strong, and has a lot of features

Browserify is simpler

Example:

```
yarn init
yarn add lodash
cat test.js
browserify test.js > output.js
```

Content of `test.js`

```
_ = require('lodash')

console.log(_.join(['hello', 'world']))
```

Now you can load `output.js` into browser